# Nested JSON to CSV design using Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python and trying figure out a requirement where I have to parse a nested JSON to CSV.

Please note that the "topping" path also selected multiple objects in some cases. So for every top-level object matched by the "paths" constructor option, we get 'm*n' rows, where 'm' is the number of matches by the "batters.batter" sub path, and 'n' is the number of matches by the "topping" sub path.

JSON:

```
[{"item":
                    {
                        "id": "0001",
                        "type": "donut",
                        "name": "Cake",
                        "ppu": 0.55,
                        "batters":
                            {
                                "batter":
                                    [
                                        { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                                        { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                                        { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                                        { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                                    ]
                            },
                        "topping":
                            [
                                { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
                                { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                                { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
                                { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
                                { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
                                { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                                { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
                            ]
                    }

}]
```

Code:

```
import sys
import json
import csv

def to_string(s):
    try:
        return str(s)
    except:
        # Change the encoding type if needed
        return s.encode('utf-8')


##
# This function converts an item like
# {
#   "item_1":"value_11",
#   "item_2":"value_12",
#   "item_3":"value_13",
#   "item_4":["sub_value_14", "sub_value_15"],
#   "item_5":{
#       "sub_item_1":"sub_item_value_11",
#       "sub_item_2":["sub_item_value_12", "sub_item_value_13"]
#   }
# }
# To
# {
#   "node_item_1":"value_11",
#   "node_item_2":"value_12",
#   "node_item_3":"value_13",
#   "node_item_4_0":"sub_value_14",
#   "node_item_4_1":"sub_value_15",
#   "node_item_5_sub_item_1":"sub_item_value_11",
#   "node_item_5_sub_item_2_0":"sub_item_value_12",
#   "node_item_5_sub_item_2_0":"sub_item_value_13"
# }
##
def reduce_item(key, value):
    global reduced_item

    # Reduction Condition 1
    if type(value) is list:
        i = 0
        for sub_item in value:
            reduce_item(key + '_' + to_string(i), sub_item)
            i = i + 1

    # Reduction Condition 2
    elif type(value) is dict:
        sub_keys = value.keys()
        for sub_key in sub_keys:
            reduce_item(key + '_' + to_string(sub_key), value[sub_key])

    # Base Condition
    else:
        reduced_item[to_string(key)] = to_string(value)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 4:
        print("\nUsage: python json_to_csv.py <node> <json_in_file_path> <csv_out_file_path>\n")
    else:
        # Reading arguments
        node = sys.argv[1]
        json_file_path = sys.argv[2]
        csv_file_path = sys.argv[3]

        fp = open(json_file_path, 'r')
        json_value = fp.read()
        raw_data = json.loads(json_value)
        fp.close()

        try:
            data_to_be_processed = raw_data[node]
        except:
            data_to_be_processed = raw_data

        processed_data = []
        header = []
        for item in data_to_be_processed:
            reduced_item = {}
            reduce_item(node, item)

            header += reduced_item.keys()

            processed_data.append(reduced_item)

        header = list(set(header))
        header.sort()

        with open(csv_file_path, 'w+') as f:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(f, header, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            writer.writeheader()
            for row in processed_data:
                writer.writerow(row)

        print("Just completed writing csv file with %d columns" % len(header))
```

When I am running the code:

```
C:\Users\user1>python C:/Users/user1/PycharmProjects/pro1/venv/file3.py item D:/jsonfile1.json D:/filecsv2.csv
Just completed writing csv file with 26 columns
```

Getting Unexpected Output:

```
"item_item_batters_batter_0_id","item_item_batters_batter_0_type","item_item_batters_batter_1_id","item_item_batters_batter_1_type","item_item_batters_batter_2_id","item_item_batters_batter_2_type","item_item_batters_batter_3_id","item_item_batters_batter_3_type","item_item_id","item_item_name","item_item_ppu","item_item_topping_0_id","item_item_topping_0_type","item_item_topping_1_id","item_item_topping_1_type","item_item_topping_2_id","item_item_topping_2_type","item_item_topping_3_id","item_item_topping_3_type","item_item_topping_4_id","item_item_topping_4_type","item_item_topping_5_id","item_item_topping_5_type","item_item_topping_6_id","item_item_topping_6_type","item_item_type"

"1001","Regular","1002","Chocolate","1003","Blueberry","1004","Devil's Food","0001","Cake","0.55","5001","None","5002","Glazed","5005","Sugar","5007","Powdered Sugar","5006","Chocolate with Sprinkles","5003","Chocolate","5004","Maple","donut"
```

I want the expected output:

```
id  type    name    batter  topping
0001    donut   Cake    Regular None
0001    donut   Cake    Regular Glazed
0001    donut   Cake    Regular Sugar
0001    donut   Cake    Regular Powdered Sugar
0001    donut   Cake    Regular Chocolate with Sprinkles
0001    donut   Cake    Regular Chocolate
0001    donut   Cake    Regular Maple
0001    donut   Cake    Chocolate   None
0001    donut   Cake    Chocolate   Glazed
0001    donut   Cake    Chocolate   Sugar
0001    donut   Cake    Chocolate   Powdered Sugar
0001    donut   Cake    Chocolate   Chocolate with Sprinkles
0001    donut   Cake    Chocolate   Chocolate
0001    donut   Cake    Chocolate   Maple
0001    donut   Cake    Blueberry   None
0001    donut   Cake    Blueberry   Glazed
0001    donut   Cake    Blueberry   Sugar
0001    donut   Cake    Blueberry   Powdered Sugar
0001    donut   Cake    Blueberry   Chocolate with Sprinkles
0001    donut   Cake    Blueberry   Chocolate
0001    donut   Cake    Blueberry   Maple
0001    donut   Cake    Devil's Food    None
0001    donut   Cake    Devil's Food    Glazed
0001    donut   Cake    Devil's Food    Sugar
0001    donut   Cake    Devil's Food    Powdered Sugar
0001    donut   Cake    Devil's Food    Chocolate with Sprinkles
0001    donut   Cake    Devil's Food    Chocolate
0001    donut   Cake    Devil's Food    Maple
0002    donut   Raised  Regular None
0002    donut   Raised  Regular Glazed
0002    donut   Raised  Regular Sugar
0002    donut   Raised  Regular Chocolate
0002    donut   Raised  Regular Maple
0003    donut   Old Fashioned   Regular None
0003    donut   Old Fashioned   Regular Glazed
0003    donut   Old Fashioned   Regular Chocolate
0003    donut   Old Fashioned   Regular Maple
0003    donut   Old Fashioned   Chocolate   None
0003    donut   Old Fashioned   Chocolate   Glazed
0003    donut   Old Fashioned   Chocolate   Chocolate
0003    donut   Old Fashioned   Chocolate   Maple
0004    bar Bar Regular Chocolate
0004    bar Bar Regular Maple
0005    twist   Twist   Regular Glazed
0005    twist   Twist   Regular Sugar
0006    filled  Filled  Regular Glazed
0006    filled  Filled  Regular Powdered Sugar
0006    filled  Filled  Regular Chocolate
0006    filled  Filled  Regular Maple
```

Comment: Make your own CSV convertsor for your JSON nested input format.